# Physical significance: multiplying matrix by outer product of its eigenvector

Tags: r, matrix-decomposition, eigenvalues

I stumbled around this piece of code:

```
v1 <- eigen(X.center %*% t(X.center))$vectors[,1]

X.0 <- v1 %*% t(v1) %*% X.center
```

while v1 is the eigenvector corresponding to the highest eigenvalue,v1%*%t(v1) gives the outer product of v1, what  X.0 signifies then and what is its physical significance? And I guess this is not a quadratic form. Can somebody point to some relevant examples please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In order to assign physical significance to the formula above, I would think you need to give some sort of physical meaning to your data.  No, X.0 is not a quadratic form.  Geometrically, the matrix $v1 %*% t(v1)$ is a rank 1 matrix that spans the column space of $v1$. Knowing what $X.center$ is might help expand this line of thought.

Comment: The X.center matrix was derived by subtracting the column mean  from each values of that column, and X is the original data matrix 
X.mean <- colMeans(X);
for(j in 1:ncol(X)){
       X.center[,j] <- (X[,j] - X.mean[j])
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Geometrically, whenever $v_1$ is a unit (column) vector, left multiplication of any column vector $x$ by `v1 %*% t(v1)` (which is $v_1 \cdot v_1'$) is the projection of $x$ onto $v_1$.  In this application, $v_1$ is the first principal component of a centered matrix of columns.  Therefore, **this code computes the projection of the centered columns onto their first principal component**.

Continuing the illustrations at [Bottom to top explanation of the Mahalanobis distance?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62092/bottom-to-top-explanation-of-the-mahalanobis-distance/62147#62147), which describes this procedure in more detail, we may depict it in the two-column situation as starting with

[image: Start]

and, after finding the center and principal axis of these points as described there, doing this:

[image: Finish]

The gray arrows depict the process of (orthogonal) projection; the blue points are the results of this projection.  They all lie along the principal axis and everything is done using the point of averages (in red) as the origin.  A similar illustration appears at the end of JD Long's explanation of Principal Components Analysis (PCA) at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/2700.