# Implication of relationship between multivariate normal distribution and chi-square distribution

Tags: intuition, multivariate-normal-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

[image]

I am wondering what is the implication of the above relation/theorem. I know how to prove this using "sphering $Y$" but I am failing to get intuitive understanding of the theorem. What does it mean for $(Y-\mu)'\Sigma^{-1}(Y-\mu)$ to be distributed as $\chi^{2}_{n}$ ? What is the implication?

Comment: For uni-variate variable you know that $\frac{y-\mu}{\sigma} \sim N(0,1)$ and the square of standard normal is $\chi^2(1)$

Now you can extend it to multivariate cases and  remember that $(Y-\mu)'\Sigma^{-1}(Y-\mu)$ is quadratic forms

Comment: So, my question is,what's the intuitive implication of quadratic form  $(Y-\mu)'\Sigma^{-1}(Y-\mu)$ having same distribution as $\chi^{2}_{n}$

Comment: What do you mean by "intuitive implication"? In some settings, it is a *useful* result. Are you asking for examples of its uses?

Comment: The final picture in my [explanation of Mahalanobis distance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/62147/919) illustrates the sense in which $(Y-\mu)^\prime\Sigma^{-1}(Y-\mu)$ is a sum of squares of standard Normal variables and therefore has a $\chi^2_n$ distribution (by definition).  Maybe that's sufficiently intuitive?

Comment: would you mind tell me the where you have seen this distribution? i wanna cite this, thx

Comment: @julia Linear Models Theory texts are a good thing to check out for this, such as Graybill's (I believe his quad form results are in Chapter 2? Don't have it on me though).

Answer (score 1):

If you by "intuitive understanding" mean how you can see this result instantly *i your mind's eye*:

- subtracting $\mu$ centers to zero mean
- rewrite the quadratic form to $ \left[\Sigma^{-1/2}(Y-\mu)\right]^T \left[\Sigma^{-1/2}(Y-\mu)\right]$. Calculate the covariance matrix of the bracketed term, you will find it is the identity matrix.
- This shows that the quadratic form has **the same distribution as the sum of squares of $n$ iid standard normal random variables.

It is not clear what you mean by asking

> I am wondering what is the implication of the above relation/theorem

The only implication is that you now know the distribution of the quadratic form, and that might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

What it says to me is that every chi square distribution can be thought of as describing the variance of a symmetric multivariate normal distribution (smnd). Which might be a very easy visualization of the kind of question the chi square is asking. This would relate to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Interval , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#History and the last 2 sentences (scroll up) above
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Probability_density_function

So a chi square test is asking how well your data corresponds to a multivariate normal distribution of appropriate dimensionality (which you specify using degrees of freedom) this measures whether your data is likely to arise randomly based on multinomial assumptions. agree?

Comment: Do you really mean "multinomial" and not "multinormal"?  This is a common typographical error.  Not all chi-squared tests are tests of multinomial distributions and in such cases the chi-squared distribution is just an approximation, anyway, suggesting the reference (if it is intended) is at best tangential to the current question.

Comment: I say multinomial based on the link to wikipedia: " ...Pearson showed that the chi-squared distribution arose from such a multivariate normal approximation to the multinomial distribution, taking careful account of the statistical dependence..."  I dont grok middle terms as well as geometrical visualizations so I may have made an error.