# Distance measure for binomial data

Tags: binomial-distribution, outliers, distance, discrete-data

Assume a distribution for the normal data and test each point $\vec {x}[κ]$ for distance from the mean. A widely used distance measure is the [Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance).

If the data are not normal, but binomial could you tell me please if there is a similar distance measure?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "similar"?  Could you explain why you think the Mahalanobis distance does not apply to binomial data?  For a definition and interpretation of Mahalanobis distance that makes no use of a Normality assumption, please see http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/62147/919.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I mean an appropriate model for binomial data. I read here https://books.google.gr/books?id=SiO5zNb-emMC&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=squared+mahalanobis+distance+intuitively&source=bl&ots=-4HLt4yqDz&sig=ScwV8euYPEkagYz-sbn1Y96vR94&hl=el&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPoJvK1uzPAhUCbhQKHeAHAG44ChDoAQgpMAE#v=onepage&q=squared%20mahalanobis%20distance%20intuitively&f=false that this measure works for approximately normal data. Moreover, I read the answer that you proposed and from the 4th bullet it seems that this will not work for my data. Please, correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

As said in comments, maybe just the Mahalanobis distance could work.  But, as explained in [Intuition of the Bhattacharya Coefficient and the Bhattacharya distance?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296361/intuition-of-the-bhattacharya-coefficient-and-the-bhattacharya-distance/296604#296604)  and other places, often an alternative which might work better is the Bhattacharyya distance based on the Bhattacharyya coefficient
$$
  BC(p,q) = \sum_{k=0}^n \sqrt{p(k) q(k)}
$$
here written in the discrete case relevant for the binomial distribution. Now let $p, q$ respectively be binomial distributions with the same index $n$ and probability parameters $p,q$.  Then the Bhattacharyya coefficient becomes
$$
  BC(p,q) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (pq)^{k/2} ((1-p)(1-q))^{(n-k)/2}
$$
which can be simplified to 
$$
 BC(p,q) = (\frac{\widetilde{pq}}{\widetilde{(1-p)(1-q)}}+1)^n \widetilde{(1-p)(1-q)}^n
$$
where the symbols with a tilde over them represents the geometric mean of $p,q$ and of $(1-p),(1-q)$, respectively.  Then the Bhattacharrya distance is given by 
$$
  BD(p,q)= -\ln BC(p,q)
$$
You can easily check that if $p=q$ then this distance becomes zero.

Below is a plot of this distance function for the case $n=10$:

[image: Bhattacharrya distance binomial case]

and for the record the R code used to produce it:

```
 BD <- Vectorize( function(p, q, n) {
    PQ  <-  sqrt(p*q)
  PQC <-  sqrt((1-p)*(1-q))
  -n*log((PQ/PQC)+1) - n*log(PQC)
      }
  )
x <- y <- seq(0.01, 0.99, by=0.01)
 z <- outer(x, y, FUN=function(x, y) BD(x, y, 10))
 levels <- c(seq(0.1, 1.5, by=0.2), 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.5)
image(x, y, z, col=terrain.colors(15), xlab="p", ylab="q" )
title("Bhattacharyya distance between binomial n=10")
contour(x, y, z, levels=levels, add=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something that comes from the form of distribution?

Mahalanobis distance is a form of [Bregman divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bregman_divergence), for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868924/derivation-of-mahalanobis-distance) has answer with derivation.

[These notes](http://www.stat.washington.edu/courses/stat538/winter10/Handouts/h6-exponential.pdf) contain explanation of Bregman divergence in context of exponential families (which cover binomial distribution).