# Types of parameters of a parametric family of probability distributions

Tags: probability, nonparametric

A statistical parameter is a quantity that indexes a family of probability distributions.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_parameter) has the following definition of a shape parameter:

> A shape parameter is any parameter of a probability distribution that is neither a location parameter nor a scale parameter (nor a function of either or both of these only, such as a rate parameter). Such a parameter must affect the shape of a distribution rather than simply shifting it (as a location parameter does) or stretching/shrinking it (as a scale parameter does).

Therefore we have only four types (classes/categories) of parameters of a parametric family:

- location parameters
- scale parameters
- shape parameters
- functions of location and/or scale (such as rate parameter = $\frac{1}{\text{scale}}$)

If so I have the following questions:

What is the type of parameters which we call "degrees of freedom" (for example, parameter $k$ of the Chi-squared distribution $\chi^2(k)$) ?
What is the type of parameters $n$ and $p$ of the Binomial distribution $\mathrm{Bin}(n,p)$ ?

Comment: You can determine this for yourself easily, as described (for bivariate distributions) at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/62147. The location and scale parameters establish the units of measurement on the graph of any function that determines the distribution, such as the cumulative distribution function. If erasing the labels on the value axes of two such graphs produces indistinguishable plots--that is, one can be made *identical* to the other merely by choosing appropriate units--then they have the same shape. Otherwise (by definition) they have different shapes. Draw some pictures!