# Is euclidean distance in pca rotated and scaled when $n < p$ the same for all observations?

Tags: pca, distance

I am trying to come up with an appropriate measure of the 'distance to the normal mean' in high dimensional space and I came up with a strange result, and I need some theoretical background to comprehend it.

The case scenario is that I have measurements of p correlated variables (from the curves describing the movement of a body segment for each time instant during a particular movement) for n individuals considered 'normal' and I would like to devise an 'abnormality metric' based on this normal population to evaluate the distance of new subjects ('patients') to the 'normal pattern'.

Problem: $n<<p$ and the p variables are correlated

I thought of using pca to decorrelate and reduce the number of dimensions ( retain the first d components according to some criteria). 
But, when I calculate the Euclidean distance for each of the n=35 observations using the standardised coordinates (i.e. Mahalanobis distance) **I get the exact same value for each observation**.

I suspect this is one of the consequences of $n<<p$ of the original data since this is clearly not the case when $n>p$ (for example displayed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62092/bottom-to-top-explanation-of-the-mahalanobis-distance))
I also checked that I do not get the same distance when I project a new observation on the standardised components and calculate the euclidean distance.

My questions are:

- Is there a theoretical result about this behavior (e.g. can I predict the value of the value for the distance for all points considering the covariance structure, n and p)?

  - Should I be worried about my 'distance to the normal mean' metric?

Thanks,

Comment: There is a theorem: it requires that, after centering, the $n$ points generate a space of $n-1$ dimensions.  When that's the case, my description of the Mahalanobis distance easily implies all $n$ points must lie on a common $n-2$-sphere; namely, their circumsphere, and then (just as obviously) that sphere's center must be the origin.

Comment: Great thanks, I had the intuition of this. Q1: Where can I find this theorem explained/described?; Q2: Can I predict the radius of the n-2 sphere the points lie on?

Comment: Just would like to add that in my experiment, the root mean squares are all equal to 0.9856, so close to 1...

Comment: Do you actually have 35 data points rather than 30?  ($\sqrt{34/35}=0.9856\ldots$)  You might consider computing the covariance matrix of the data rather than the covariance *estimator*: the computation of the former divides by $n$ and the latter divides by $n-1.$

Comment: Yes! It was 35 datapoints, I have edited the original  question. So, does it mean the sphere's (hyper)radius is meant to be a function of the number of observations?

Comment: No, it just means you ought to choose the appropriate formula for the covariance matrix.  Because you are comparing your data among themselves, using the Bessel correction of $n/(n-1)$ in the covariance formula is unnecessary--you're not trying to construct an unbiased estimator of anything--and only leads to this (slight) dependence of the radius with $n.$

Comment: Ok, but that was not my point. I was not (so far) controlling the calculation of the covariance matrix since Matlab's pca function does this calculation for me.

Comment: [tried to move to chat but not enough 'reputation' to do so] Sorry, I was referring to the norm of the points being dependent of the number of observations, n, as the square root of n times 1. But I forgot to mention that I was considering the norm as the radius of the (hyper)sphere. Just realised that the root mean square is probably a better way to 'define' the radius of a (hyper)sphere. I am not used to think in high dimensional space.