# Difference between standardizing variables and using Mahalanobis distance

Tags: multivariate-analysis, standardization, distance, euclidean

I am wondering how and/or why the [Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) is different from using the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) on [standardized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) variables?

Comment: Perhaps the explanation at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62092/bottom-to-top-explanation-of-the-mahalanobis-distance/62147#62147 will make the distinction clear.

Comment: Both are euclidean distances computed on the reshaped (transformed) data cloud. The reshaping is different, though. Standardization squeezes/stretches along the variable axes and that does not change correlation magnitude. Mahalanobis squeezes/stretches along the principal axes and that makes correlation zero (sphering of the cloud).

Comment: @ttnphns That's interesting. Is it valid to say that Mahalanobis distance constructs its own axes or even orthogonal system?

Comment: In a sense yes. Wikipedia on Mahalanobis explains what is going geometrically.