# Intuitive explanation of "density generators"?

Tags: normal-distribution, density-function, joint-distribution, copula

I was reading through Meucci's *[Risk and Asset Allocation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3642009646) (2005)*, when I happened upon the concept of a "density generator", which I have not been able to find good explanations for anywhere online, and would appreciate some help in understanding.

From pg. 116 of the book, the density generator, $g_N$, is introduced,

[image]

and later, on pg. 214, the normal distribution's generator is shown as

[image]

Based on searches online, it seems that density generators have to do with copulas, and represent a method of specifying tail dependence within elliptical distributions, which normally do not feature such dependence (?), as described in this [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=wn2svFgsgxQC&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=%22density%20generator%22%20statistics&source=bl&ots=98n56iEDYv&sig=ACfU3U1SLn1DvAglJ03aQ8pg-tbWrMR4Ag&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwigxb2Mm6fjAhWBGc0KHU9RChAQ6AEwBXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22density%20generator%22%20statistics&f=false).

While I grasp the basics of copula theory, some help in understanding this concept would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

An elliptical distribution is affinely equivalent to a spherically symmetric distribution.  It therefore suffices to specify the radial distribution.  By convention, it is given in terms of the distribution of the *squared radius.*  When that is continuous, its density is the *generator.*

---

This means that when an $n$-dimensional random variable $X$ has an elliptical distribution, there is a *center* $\mu\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and an invertible matrix $\Lambda$ such that the distribution of

$$Z = \Lambda^{-1}(X-\mu)$$

is the same as the distribution of $QZ$ for any orthogonal matrix $Q.$  Equivalently, *the distribution of $Z$ determines and is determined by the distribution of its squared Euclidean length*

$$|Z|^2 = Z^\prime Z = (X-\mu)^\prime \Lambda^{-1^\prime} \,\Lambda^{-1}(X-\mu) = (X-\mu)^\prime \Sigma^{-1} (X-\mu)$$

where $\Sigma=\Lambda \Lambda^\prime$ is (clearly) symmetric and positive definite.

When such a distribution is continuous it has a multivariate density $f,$ which therefore can be written in the form

$$f(x) = k\,g\left((x-\mu)^\prime \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu)\right)$$

with $k$ the constant that makes $f$ integrate to unity.  [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptical_distribution), $g$ is a *generator* of the distribution of $X.$

For example, because the standard elliptical Normal distribution has a density proportional to $$\exp(-(z_1^2+z_2^2+\cdots+z_n^2)/2) = \exp\left(-|z|^2/2\right) = g(|z|^2),$$ its generator is proportional to

$$g(z) = e^{-z/2}, z \ge 0;\ g(z) = 0, z \lt 0.$$

(It's always understood that $g$ only needs to be defined for $z\ge 0.$)

Note that $g$ is *not* the density of $|Z|^2$ nor even of $|Z|$ itself: that's because in spherical coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^n,$ $g$ must be multiplied by $|z|^{n/2-1}$ to obtain the density of $|Z|^2.$  For instance, the distribution of the squared spherical Normal radius has a density proportional to $z^{n/2-1}e^{-z/2},$ a *Chi-squared distribution.*

Because it can help to have more than one example of something, here are a few other generators.

**[The multivariate Student t distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_t-distribution)**

For the distribution with $\nu$ degrees of freedom, a generator  is

$$g_\nu(z) = \frac{1}{\left(1 + z\right)^{(\nu+n)/2}}.$$

**The multivariate uniform spherical distribution**

A generator is

$$g(z) = 1, 0 \le z\le 1;\ g(z) = 0\text{ otherwise.}$$

---

This concept of "generator" has little to do with copulas *per se* and almost nothing to do with tail behavior, either.  ($g$ determines its tail behavior, of course; but there are many possible functions $g$ associated with any radial tail behavior.)

The [account I gave of the Mahalanobis distance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/62147/919) applies equally well to understanding any multivariate distribution, showing how $\mu$ merely establishes the origin of a coordinate system and $\Sigma$ determines a set of orthogonal coordinate axes in which the multivariate distribution of $X$ has a particularly simple form.  What makes the distribution "elliptical" is that the resulting form is especially simple, depending only on the (Mahalanobis) distance from the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Generator functions of elliptical distributions is a function that characterises the tail dependency in each function. For example, normal distribution does not has a tail dependency, while t-student is symmetric tail function. A copula is just a multivariate distribution function with standard uniform margins. Normal copula function also cannot deal with tail dependency.

Comment: Can density generators be used for other distributions as well, then? Can any arbitrary, continuous distribution have a generator attached to it, that would allow it to feature tail dependence, where no existed before?

Comment: A generator function always exists. Each distribution has its own generator function. If you change the generator function of Gaussian, how can it become a Gaussian distribution?! For example, if we use the generator function of Gaussian with T-student distribution, do you think it will be still a Gaussian distribution?!  Each Archimedian copula function, for example, has its own generator function. There are some conditions that make the generator function valid or not!