# Posterior predictive distribution, linear regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, linear, posterior

The following quotation is from *[Machine Learning: a Probabilistic Perspective](https://probml.github.io/pml-book/book0.html)* Chapter 7, page 234

> In machine learning, we often care more about predictive accuracy than about interpreting the parameters. Using Equation 4.126, we can easily show that the posterior predictive distribution at a test
> point $\mathbf{x}$ is also Gaussian:
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> p(y|\mathbf{x}, \mathcal{D}, \sigma^2) &= \int\mathcal{N}\left(y|\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{w}, \sigma^2\right)\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{w}|\mathbf{w}_N, \mathbf{V}_N\right)d\mathbf{w}\\
> &=\mathcal{N}\left(y|\mathbf{w}^T_N\mathbf{x}, \sigma^2_N(\mathbf{x})\right)\\
> \sigma^2_N(\mathbf{x}) &= \sigma^2 + \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{V}_N\mathbf{x}
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> The variance in this prediction, $\sigma^2_N(x)$, depends on two terms: the variance of the observation noise, $\sigma^2$, and the variance in the parameters, $\mathbf{V}_N$. The latter translates into variance about observations in a way which depends on how close $\mathbf{x}$ is to the training data $\mathcal{D}$.

My question is in which way does "$\mathbf{V}_N$  translates into variance about observations in a way which depends on how close $\mathbf{x}$ is to the training data $\mathcal{D}$"? I mean, OK intuitively, but how can i prove it in a formal way?

Comment: The parameter variance matrix is proportional to the *Mahalanobis distance.*  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62092 for details.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that $V_N$ is the covariance matrix for the model coefficients, so it is a positive definite matrix. That makes $d(x)=x^TV_Nx$ a vector norm, in the mathematical sense: it is not the usual euclidian norm, and it will give more weight to deviances in some directions than in others, but it still satisfies the definition of a norm function. Norms can be interpreted as the distance between a point and the origin, and since $X$ is centered, the origin is the mean of the input vectors. Therefore, $d(x)=x^TV_Nx$ measures the distance between the input vector $x$ and the mean of the input in the training set.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Its right there in line 7.60.

$y$ is drawn using $\mathbf{w}$, and $\mathbf{w}$ is drawn using $V_N$.  The dependence of $y$ on $V_N$ is through $\mathbf{w}$.

Comment: I believe the OP is trying to understand how $x^\prime V_N x$ expresses "how close $x$ is to the training data."