# Why does univariate Mahalanobis distance not match z-score?

Tags: scikit-learn, outliers, univariate, mahalanobis

I am using [Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) for outlier detection. Sometimes my dataset only has 1 feature, sometimes many more. I believe the univariate Mahalanobis distance should be equal to the z-score of the data (i.e. the standardized values), but **the numbers from this `sklearn` function are consistently larger than expected.**

Here's some example code using [`sklearn.covariance.EllipticEnvelope.mahalanobis()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.covariance.EllipticEnvelope.html#sklearn.covariance.EllipticEnvelope.mahalanobis) that produces the effect:

```py
import numpy sas np
from sklearn.covariance import EllipticEnvelope

x = np.random.default_rng(42).normal(loc=1, scale=10, size=1000)
z = (x - x.mean()) / x.std()
ee = EllipticEnvelope().fit(z.reshape(-1, 1))  
sqdist = ee.mahalanobis(z.reshape(-1, 1))
```

I'm giving it the z-score here, but I could also give it the raw `x`; it doesn't affect the outcome.

Now we can compare the square root of this metric (squared Mahalanobis distance, according to the docs) to the absolute z-score, and find that they are different:

- First values of `np.abs(z)`: `[0.313  , 1.0233 , 0.75595, 0.94488, 1.92866]`
- First values of `np.sqrt(sqdist)`: `[0.34309, 1.12069, 0.82829, 1.03524, 2.11241]`

The distributions are look like this:

```py
import seaborn as sns

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 3), sharey=True)
sns.histplot(np.abs(z), ax=axs[0])
sns.histplot(np.sqrt(sqdist), ax=axs[1])
```

[image: Histogram of the absolute z-scores compared to this metric]

I expected these metrics to be identical, so one of the following things must be true:

- The univariate Mahalanobis distance is not equal to the Z-score. If this is the case, then how are they related?
- The metric produced by this function (which is the same as `ee.dist_`) is not the true squared Mahalanobis distance, either because of a definition or a bug (seems unlikely).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your intuition about the Mahalanobis distance is correct. However, the *EllipticEnvelope* algorithm computes robust estimates of the location and covariance matrix which don't match the raw estimates. (See the scikit-learn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.covariance.EllipticEnvelope.html) for details.) In practice, this means that the *z* scores you compute by hand are not equal to (the square root of) the Mahalanobis distances.

First we sample from a univariate Normal and we compute the raw estimates of the mean and variance parameters.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.covariance import EllipticEnvelope

x = np.random.default_rng(42).normal(loc=1, scale=10, size=1000)

x.mean()
#> 0.71108449
x.var()
#> 97.75718960
```

The robust estimates are not equal to the raw estimates. (location = mean, precision = 1 / variance).

```py
ee = EllipticEnvelope()
ee = ee.fit(x.reshape(-1, 1))

ee.location_
#> array([1.09312831])
1 / ee.precision_
#> array([[79.27975244]])
```

As a result, the "raw" *z* scores are not equal to the "robust" *z* scores.

```py
dist = ee.mahalanobis(x.reshape(-1, 1))

robust_mean = ee.location_
robust_std = 1 / np.sqrt(ee.precision_[0, 0])

np.vstack([
    np.sqrt(dist),
    np.abs(x - x.mean()) / x.std(),
    np.abs(x - robust_mean) / robust_std
])
#> array([[0.33176884, 1.17846656, 0.83237332, ..., 0.12563584, 0.13640215, 0.91469881],
#>        [0.33741386, 1.02262536, 0.78823215, ..., 0.15178124, 0.16147682, 0.86237019],
#>        [0.33176884, 1.17846656, 0.83237332, ..., 0.12563584, 0.13640215, 0.91469881]])
```

Hopefully, this is instructive. It seems to me that first computing *z* scores, as you do, and then "robustifying" them to find outliers defeats the purpose. Instead apply *EllipticEnvelope* to the original features and trust the method to come up with reliable estimates of the mean and the covariance.