# How to reconstruct Cartesian coordinates from a Gram matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I read [this article](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2019/SC/C9SC02742D) and am wondering why we can reconstruct Cartesian coordinates from a Gram matrix generated by taking dot product of the distance from the origin.
They had a Euclidean distance matrix. They generated a Gram matrix by $$G=-\frac12(D-1d_1^\top-d_11^\top).$$  Then, an eigenvalue decomposition is conducted on $G$ by $\Lambda_G=U_GGU_G^\top.$

Now, I don't understand why we can get the Cartesian coordinate by $\Lambda_G^{1/2}U_G^\top.$  Could anyone explain that simply?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/62147/919 provides a visual explanation.