# Linear regression: p-value for linearHypothesis() in R

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

Let's start with the `Davis` dataset from `car` package and fit a simple regression model

```
data(Davis)
mod.davis <- lm(weight ~ repwt, data = Davis)
summary(mod.davis)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   5.3363     3.0369   1.757   0.0806 .  
repwt         0.9278     0.0453  20.484   <2e-16 ***
```

Now I'd like to test
\begin{align*}
\beta_0 &= 5 \\
\beta_1 &= 1
\end{align*}

```
linearHypothesis(mod.davis, c("(Intercept) = 5", "repwt = 1"))
```

what I get is

```
  Res.Df   RSS Df Sum of Sq      F    Pr(>F)    
1    183 16549                                  
2    181 12828  2      3721 26.251 9.764e-11 ***
```

The low p-value is quite puzzling for me

```
confint(mod.davis)
                 2.5 %    97.5 %
(Intercept) -0.6560394 11.328560
repwt        0.8384665  1.017219
```

especially because of the fact, that for
\begin{align*}
\beta_0 &= 0 \\
\beta_1 &= 1
\end{align*}

```
linearHypothesis(mod.davis, c("(Intercept) = 0", "repwt = 1"))

  Res.Df   RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1    183 13074                           
2    181 12828  2    245.97 1.7353 0.1793
```

the data suggests that $H_0$ is true. How is that? $\beta_0 = 5.33$ is the mean of the sampling distribution, so I'd expect a p-value $< 0.05$ rather for testing for $\beta_0=0$.

Comment: Your intercept is the predicted outcome at 0, which for a body weight measurement seems nonsensical & will be quite the extrapolation. Have you considered centering your data?

Comment: A standard application where this issue comes up occurs when the explanatory variable is time.  For instance, if you were to regress some time series against a numeric year C.E., the intercept would be the fitted value *at the year zero.*  As far as your joint hypothesis goes, bear in mind the intercept estimate can be *strongly* correlated with the slope estimate.  The only time this doesn't occur is with centered variables.

Comment: @whuber I see, but what's the reason for the discrepancy here? I don't quite get it.

Comment: I don't see any discrepancy.  Please *plot* your data and your hypothesis.  This will help: `with(Davis, plot(repwt, weight, xlim = c(0, 130), ylim = c(0, 5*130)));
abline(c(1, 5))`  How plausible is this hypothesis??

Comment: @whuber I believe that there should be `abline(5,1)` and then it doesn't look particularly wrong. I get the fact that the CI for the intercept is quite wide, but still it isn't clear to me why testing for "the most probable" value of the intercept yields to such a small p-value.

Comment: You are performing a **joint** F-test on both parameters, as already mentioned these will likely be highly correlated. Have a look at just the hypothesis test for $\beta_0=5$ (I'll tell you: P = 0.912). The test for $\beta_0=0$ under your model will return the same *P*-value as the one for having observed $\hat{\beta_0}=5.3363$ under the null. (I keep messing up the TeX in these comments...)

Comment: I tried some things:

`linearHypothesis(mod.davis, "(Intercept) = 5")  # p = 0.912`
`linearHypothesis(mod.davis, "repwt = 1") #p = 0.113`
`linearHypothesis(mod.davis, "repwt = 0.93") #p = 0.96`

Considering the low SE for the parameter estimate of repwt,  p = 0.113 for the first test makes sense.

Comment: Sorry--I did mix them up.  But plotting still resolves the question: you can see how the plotted line exceeds all but two or three of the 200 points in the scatterplot, *convincingly* demonstrating it's incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Let's *look* at the data and your hypothesis.**

The first figure is a plot you should always make: a scatterplot of the data.  On it I have drawn a 95% confidence band for the fit (in gray) and your hypothesis in red, the line with intercept 5 and slope 1:

[image]

The red line is not a good fit: almost all of the nearly 200 points in the plot lie below it.  But does it really deserve a p-value as low as $10^{-10}$?

**One way to get some intuition is to simulate these data.**  This isn't something you would routinely do, but doing it at least once is a good part of any statistical education and is a great way to check your analysis is correct.

Here, I sample from the estimated parameters (slope and intercept) using their estimated variance-covariance matrix.  The next plot shows 50 such samples, each drawn as a gray line.

[image]

It shows, among other things, that the hypothesized line isn't close to any of these 50 lines: all of those simulated lines tend to go near the "point of averages" near $(66,66),$ whereas the hypothesized line is visibly higher there.

Perhaps a clearer way to see how unlikely the hypothesis is uses the more abstract method of plotting the slopes and intercepts as *points.*  (This is the "parameter space" in which the possible values of (intercept, slope) lie.)  This time I show 500 simulated values as faint points and their density as a colored contour plot.

[image]

The red point is the hypothesized line. Its extremely low p-value reflects two things:

- The point is visibly far from any of the simulated data, *especially* in the northeast - southwest direction.  That is, it might not be far from any of the intercepts (it's not) and it might not be far from any of the slopes (it's not), but it truly is a "geometric outlier" when examined in the full context.  (Its [Mahalanobis distance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/62147/919) is large.)
- The p-value is computed assuming these points follow a bivariate Normal density.  Such densities decay *extremely* quickly away from their centers (their logarithms, by definition, decrease *parabolically* -- that is, their decrease accelerates with distance).

If you make a different distributional assumptions about the errors in the data, you will obtain different p-values: but clearly they will all be small, because this hypothesis is a poor description of the data.

Comment: Thank you! Brilliant and very insightful answer, as always. I guess I kinda fell for the trap that I always try to avoid: I trusted the OLS parameters far too much, beyond the resonable point. Thanks again!

Comment: @whuber This answer is great [+1] I wonder if you might show the code that you used to generate these plots ? I would be obliged!

Comment: @Cooper The first two plots are routine.  The last is a 2D density plot of the dataframe `A` created using the `mvrnorm` multivariate Normal RNG in the `MASS` library: `library(car);
library(MASS)
mod.davis <- lm(weight ~ repwt, data = Davis);
b <- coefficients(mod.davis);
S <- vcov(mod.davis);
A <- as.data.frame(mvrnorm(500, b, S))`

Comment: @whuber thank you ever so much :)