Rescaling for unit variance before finding Mahalanobis distance?
I am reading up on Mahalanobis distance and Principal Component Analysis.  According to this description (Section 3), the data is transformed into into uncorrelated variables before rescaling to unit variance.  I assume that transforming into uncorrelated variables is expressing the data coordinates along the principal component axes.  This seems odd, as PCA is sensitive to the relative scaling of the data along the original axes.
According to this and this page, rescaling to unit variance is done before PCA.  Can I assume that the above description of rescaling afterward is not entirely accurate? Section 4 of the same page multiplies the centred raw data by the inverse of the covariance matrix, which loosely like a standardization to unit variance.  But I typically get tripped up by the math, so I want to make sure my intuition is correct before trying to decipher the math.
Elaboration on my points of confusion
In my muddy mind, it seems conceivable that a 1st scaling #1 is done at the front end of PCA, and once the principal component axes are identified, a 2nd scaling #2 is done along the principal component axes before measuring the Mahalanobis distance. After all, there may still be visually recognizable correlation after scaling #1, meaning more scatter along the 1st principal component than the 2nd. Therefore, you'd still need rescaling to get somewhat spherically uniform scatter.
whuber's explanation does say that given the covariance function $C$ and points $x$ and $y$, $\sqrt{(x−y)′\:C^{−1}(x−y)}$ "works regardless of what basis is used to represent vectors and matrices" (the italicization is mine). This makes me think that it doesn't matter if rescaling is done before identifying principal components and/or (possibly again) before taking the Mahalanobis distance? I'm also unclear about the reference to covariance function $C$ (I've only read about a covariance matrix).

Perhaps you will find explanations here on CV to be a little clearer.  How about https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62092?  It contains some relatively low-math explanations.

@whuber: I actually did see that in my web wanderings.  I also reviewed eigenvalues/vectors, diagonalization, linear transforms, etc. But I'm still muddy on whether scaling to unit variance is done on the raw data and axes before identifying the principal components, which gets rid of misleading scaling effects due to choice of measuring units in the raw data.

No need to use quotation marks: I explicitly write $C$ as a function of two variables--which is what it is.  It's a symmetric quadratic form; equivalently, it's the square of a Euclidean metric.

I used quotes to pinpoint the wording with which I was confused, but I understand that it may convey other connotations.  I've instead replaced it with italics.  I'll take a closer look at your comment above....time passes....your explanation says "Letting $C$ stand for the covariance function".  What is the relationship between $C$ and the covariance matrix?

Based on this visualization of covariance matrix, I believe that I am conflating: (i) standardization to unit variance with (ii) rescaling along individual axes. The effect of multiplication by the inverse of the covariance matrix is to rotate the data so that the principal component axes are used for the coordinate system. The covariance between axes is then zero, so the rescaling can be done independently along individual axes such that the variances along the axes are 1.0.

The said rescaling compensates for any scale issues in calculating the distances using the untransformed data. This is well summarized here. If the above is correct, I wonder if it constitutes an answer (keeping in mind that the question is seeking an intuitive way to visualize what is happening).

The covariance matrix defines the function.  I recommend that you read up on the relevant elements of linear algebra, especially symmetric quadratic forms, because that is likely to be of help in understanding the notation, terminology, and the concepts.

You may find it an easy memo that Mahalanobis distances computed on the data are (equal to) Euclidean distances computed on standardized principal components of the data. St. principal components are "whitened" (decorrelated and uniscaled) data.

@whuber: It may be due to the fact that my background is not in mathematics, but I'm having difficulty getting the intuition from that Wikipedia page on quadratic forms, and the section on symmetric quadratic forms.

That's why I wrote my post on Mahalanobis distances and commented that the dimension alone characterizes all real (nondegenerate) quadratic forms.  That means they are all the ordinary Euclidean distances we all know and love.  IMHO, that's an awful lot of intuition!

@whuber: Are you referring to this post?  I searched for the string "quadratic" and couldn't find where you make that comment.  Also, by "dimension" in your comment, do you mean the number of axes in the data?

After sleeping on this, it seems to me that the Mahalanobis is not standardizing the data to have unit variance along the original axes before finding the principal components.  This is because it is using the covariance matrix for the raw data.  After identifying the principal components, the standardization to unit variance is done along the axes corresponding to the principal components.  Does this make sense?

If the above makes sense, why is it OK to identify the principal components without prior rescaling when that's not how its done in PCA?  On the other hand, if it doesn't make sense, is there an intuitive way to show what is really happening?

Yes, your interpretation makes sense.  But I don't understand what you're trying to ask in your last comment, which seems to be based on a limited concept of what "PCA" is.  In particular, PCA does not require any form of centering, scaling, or other normalization and it yields several different (but closely related) outputs such as unit eigenvectors, eigenvectors scaled by eigenvalues, and so forth.  That's why I'm not following what you might mean by "what is really happening" and can only reiterate that my post (among others) is an attempt at an accurate description of the Mahalanobis dist.

@whuber: You said "PCA does not require any form of centering, scaling".  That hits the nail of my question, which includes 3 links indicating otherwise, along with the reasoning.  I'm less sure about the 3rd link because it uses sklearn rather than discussing the concepts.

I will, with some diffidence and no lack of respect, like to suggest that any page that includes "machine learning" prominently might not include a good general description of PCA.

It's more pervasive than just those links.  I just googled the dash-separated phrase does-pca-require-rescaling-beforehand.  There is some ambiguity, but there seems to be an overwhelming consensus on rescaling along the original axes (my perception).  I wonder if this is the kind of question with no black-and-white answer.
