What is the meaning of term "whiten" data in relation to Mahalanobis Distance?
I'm writing my thesis and I have trouble in understanding the paper: https://people.bu.edu/bkulis/pubs/ftml_metric_learning.pdf
My major is not mathematics, but I can understand the basic so I hope you can help me to understand with basic words
I the section 2.2.1 The Mahalanobis Distance.
As far as I know is that, Mahalnobis distance is calculate the Euclidean distance between data points after they are "whitened" (as I understand is convert the distribution of the data into Gaussian (normal distribution) which has mean is 0 and covariance is identity matrix. Wow, but it won't lose the correlation distances between data points right?
By the way, Is there any intuition in doing this? like the shape of the data in the first place might be ellipse and tilt left, after transform it's gonna be circle and vertical right? Does it do anything with noise?
Finally sorry as I'm not native, I don't understand the term "whiten" how you express the meaning of whiten here
Thank you

This is a credibly written Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitening_transformation

Concerning your questions about intuition behind the Mahalanobis distance, please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62092.
