# Can I combine two continuous variables to fit a linear mixed model?

Tags: correlation, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, continuous-data, paired-data

Suppose a dataset as follows:

```
data <- data.frame(X = c(1.2, 1.5, 1.7, 1.8, 2.0, 2.2, 2.3, 2.5),
                    Y = c(3.2, 3.5, 3.7, 3.8, 4.0, 4.2, 4.3, 4.5),
                    technique = factor(rep(c("A", "B"), each = 4)),
                    county = factor(rep(1:4, times = 2)))
data

    X   Y technique county
1 1.2 3.2         A      1
2 1.5 3.5         A      2
3 1.7 3.7         A      3
4 1.8 3.8         A      4
5 2.0 4.0         B      1
6 2.2 4.2         B      2
7 2.3 4.3         B      3
8 2.5 4.5         B      4
```

I have four counties, on each of which two techniques were used to calculate X and Y.

I want to test if there are significant differences in X and Y based on the two techniques used. I can do separately for X and Y using LMMs:

```r
m.X <- lmer(X ~ technique + (1 | county), data = data) #for response X

m.Y <- lmer(Y ~ technique + (1 | county), data = data) #for response Y
```

**My question now is: Is there any statistical technique where I can combine X and Y to create a single response, say `Z` and test the effect of technique and county on the single response?**

Comment: `+`? `*`? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @AlexJ : https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/35926/257284 something like this. I think I found a lead.